# |3x-15|<6+|9-9x/5| Find the range of values of x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve this modulus inequality? I don't understand the ways to do this question such as squaring and taking out the modulus twice.Can someone explain the ways to do this question?Thanks!

Comment: Best way to see what's going on in this kind of thing is to sketch the functions involved: $y=|3x-15|$ and $y=6+|9-9x/5|$ and try to find region in which inequality is true, then try to express it in analytic way

Comment: But other than graphical ways,is there another way?

Comment: you can do case work

Comment: It's easy to see that both functions achieve minimum at $x=5$ and at that point RHS is $6$ and LHS is $0$, and both functions are symmetric about the line $x=5$ due to their definition, and we see that $|3x-15|>6+|9-9x/5|$ for large enough $x$, so you can just find solutions to the equation $|3x-15|=6+|9-9x/5|$ and inequality is true iff $x$ lies between the two solutions

Comment: Case work?sorry,my teacher didn't really go through this type of questions yet..

Comment: Is "9-9x/5" $9-\frac{9}{5}x$ ?

Comment: Sorry,I know the minimum value of x is 5 but what difference does that?Sorry,I'm lost for these type without an example...sorry

Comment: @mathlove 9-(9x/5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your inequality is equivalent to
$$3|x-5|<6+9|1-x/5|$$ this is equivalent to
$$15|x-5|<30+9|x-5|$$ and now you have to solve
$$6|x-5|<30$$ or $$|x-5|<5$$
and this is easy

Comment: Wow...how to 'see' these type of questions?

Comment: we solved a lot of such problems in our math circle in Leipzig with Ferdinand Wagner how goes to the next IMO

Comment: Thanks a lot...this is a much easier way

Comment: you are wellcome i'm waiting for your next problem

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Note that:
$$
3x-15\ge 0 \quad \iff \quad x\ge 5
$$
and
$$
9-\frac{9}{5}x\ge 0 \quad \iff \quad x\le 5
$$
so your inequality is equivalent to the two systems:
$$
\begin{cases}
x\ge 5\\
3x-15<6+\frac{9}{5}x-9 
\end{cases}
\quad \lor \quad
\begin{cases}
x\le 5\\
15-3x<6+9-\frac{9}{5}x 
\end{cases}
$$

can you do from this?

Comment: So I do the comparing when x is more than 5 and x is less than 5?Correct?

Comment: In your system of inequalities you probably meant $3x-15$ on LHS?

Comment: Modulus on both sides of inequality

Comment: @user340297 Yes thank you! I edit the typo..:)